# How to remove data-* attributes using the HTML dataset attribute

Tags: javascript, dom, custom-data-attribute

According to [the dataset specification](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#dom-dataset), how is [element.dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.dataset) meant to delete data attributes? Consider:

```
<p id="example" data-a="string a" data-b="string b"></p>
```

If you do this:

```
var elem = document.querySelector('#example');
elem.dataset.a = null;
elem.dataset.b = undefined;
elem.dataset.c = false;
elem.dataset.d = 3;
elem.dataset.e = [1, 2, 3];
elem.dataset.f = {prop: 'value'};
elem.dataset.g = JSON.stringify({prop: 'value'});
```

the DOM becomes this in Chrome and Firefox:

```
<p id="example" 
   data-a="null" 
   data-b="undefined" 
   data-c="false" 
   data-d="3" 
   data-e="1,2,3" 
   data.f="[object Object]" 
   data.g="{"prop":"value"}"
></p>
```

The Chrome/Firefox implementations mimic [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.setAttribute). It basically applies `.toString()` first. This makes sense to me except for the treatment of `null` because I would expect that `null` would remove the attribute. Otherwise how does the dataset API do the equivalent of:

```
elem.removeAttribute('data-a');
```

And what about boolean attributes:

`<p data-something>` is equivalent to `<p data-something="">` Hmm.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Wouldn't 'delete' remove dataset element? E.g.:

```
<div id="a1" data-foo="bar">test</div>

<script>
var v = document.getElementById('a1');  
alert(v.dataset.foo);
delete v.dataset.foo;
alert(v.dataset.foo);
</script>
```

Comment: Note; `delete v.dataset.foo;` will not work in Safari. A cross browser solution would be; `v.removeAttribute('data-foo')`

Comment: @maximdim, can you please update your answer to include the comment from Jeremy? Even in Safari 10, this is still an issue. Safari 11 fixes this (checked with Safari Technical Preview)

Comment: Jeremy's answer is not entirely correct. If value is assigned programmatically (`v.dataset.foo = 'bar'`) then `removeAttribute` does not have the same effect as `delete v.dataset.foo` — it doesn't delete the property from dataset

Comment: @ips It does.  v.dataset dynamically reflects the values of the attribuites, it's not a separate object.

Comment: `delete v.dataset.foo` works on my mac with safari 11.1.2

Answer (score 8):

A rather simpler and straightforward approach:

```
const someElement = document.querySelector('...');

Object.keys(someElement.dataset).forEach(dataKey => {
  delete someElement.dataset[dataKey];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset) you need to use the delete operator to remove a dataset element

> When you want to remove an attribute, you can use the delete operator.

```js
const p = document.getElementById('example')
delete p.dataset.a
delete p.dataset.b
```

Answer (score 0):

This is to remove all the data-* attributes. You can add a condition in the for loop to remove only particular data-attribute. Hope this helps :)

```
var elem = document.querySelector('#example');
var dataset = elem.dataset;
for (var key in dataset) {
    elem.removeAttribute("data-" + key.split(/(?=[A-Z])/).join("-").toLowerCase());
}
```

Answer (score -7):

```
<div data-id="test">test</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div").removeAttr("data-id"); // removing the data attributes.
  console.log($("div").data("id")); // displays in the console.
});
```