# How to add boolean attribute using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom-manipulation

How do you add boolean attributes using JavaScript? For example, how can you change:

`<p>` to `<p contenteditable>`

`<p>` to `<p data-example>`

Comment: Those are HTML attributes. Whether they are boolean in nature doesn't really mater. For contenteditable, you can treat it as a standard HTML attribute/value pair `contenteditable="true"`

Comment: @DA It does matter if you want to set them using the IDL property rather than through `setAttribute()`. For example, the `selected` boolean property, can receive the boolean values `true` or `false`, while the attribute value should either be `selected` (`selected="selected"`) or the empty string (`selected` or `selected=""`).

Comment: @DA In the spec they're referred to as boolean attributes http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.3.4.2

Comment: `contenteditable` is not a boolean attribute. See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9201499/96656

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications! Yes, I was incorrect. A true boolean variable can only have a value of itself. I guess what I was getting at is that regardless of whether or not it's boolean, you can treat it like any other html entity in that it can have a value. That said, I'm not up on what IDL is so that could very well be something entirely different.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In general, you can use `element.setAttribute('attributeName', 'value')` or `element.propertyName = value` to toggle an element’s attributes or properties.

### Boolean attributes

For boolean attributes, set the attribute with the same-named value:

```
element.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Removing a boolean attribute works the same way as other attributes:

```
element.removeAttribute('disabled');
```

However, neither of your two examples are [boolean attributes](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attributes)!

### `contenteditable`

`contenteditable` is *not* a boolean attribute, it’s an enumerated attribute. Its possible values are the empty string, `"true"`, and `"false"`.

While `setAttribute` seems overkill in this case, you could use it:

```
element.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true');
// to undo:
element.removeAttribute('contenteditable');
```

The property name for the `contenteditable` attribute is `contentEditable` (note the capital `E`), and [it recognizes the values](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/editing.html#contenteditable) `'true'`, `'false'`, and `'inherit'` — so you could just use:

```
element.contentEditable = 'true';
// to undo:
element.contentEditable = 'false';
```

Note that `'true'` and `'false'` are strings here, not booleans.

### `data-example`

For the `data-example` attribute, you could use:

```
element.setAttribute('data-example', 'some value'); // the value should be a string
// to undo:
element.removeAttribute('data-example');
```

Or, in browsers who support `dataset` (see the ones highlighted in light green on http://caniuse.com/dataset), you could use:

```
element.dataset.example = 'some value';
```

Comment: Ah yea enumerated :] Comparing an empty string `"" === elem.getAttribute('contenteditable')` is `true` in JavaScript. But if you compare it to any of those other values it's `false`. 
In the browser for contenteditable both "the empty string and the true keyword map to the true state" http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#contenteditable

Comment: @ryanve Well of course; `'' == ''` in JavaScript, so if you use `<p contenteditable>` or `<p contenteditable="">`, `p.getAttribute('contenteditable') == ''`.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @kleinfreund Depends on which question you’re referring to. OP’s example (which doesn’t have any boolean attributes in it!) makes it clear that they didn’t actually mean to ask the question from the title. Answering it doesn’t help their case. I answered the question that solves OP’s problem.

Comment: @MathiasBynens I don’t agree with the assertion that the question doesn’t contain boolean attributes. The definition/usage of `data-example` is unknown and may be a boolean attribute. You do not provide an answer to the question raised via the title or the body of the question. You could’ve provided a direct answer plus your current answer based on assumption.

Comment: @MathiasBynens Your answer is still valuable and raises some important, easy to miss aspects the OP or other readers might not have considered.

Comment: @kleinfreund That’s incorrect. **Custom attributes cannot be [boolean attributes](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attributes), by definition!** You could _kind of_ treat a custom attribute as if it was boolean, but it would still behave differently than a real boolean attribute.

Comment: @MathiasBynens I don’t see where on that page it is implied that custom attributes cannot be boolean. I can’t find a source for that in the spec. (In the third example [here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#custom-data-attribute), there is a custom attribute used effectively like a boolean.) Is your point that the interfaces for custom attributes don’t provide the means of interacting with them like they were boolean attributes?

Comment: @kleinfreund An example boolean attribute is `hidden`. `<p hidden>` or `<p hidden="">` or `<p hidden="hidden">` are all equivalent. Any attribute that is not defined as a boolean attribute in the spec (including custom attributes) does not magically get that behavior. For custom attributes you’d have to implement something like it yourself, and still it wouldn’t be a real boolean property as it wouldn’t go through the same pipeline in the browser.

Comment: @MathiasBynens I think that's helpful information to add to your answer in order to understand your intentions.

Answer (score 44):

## To add a Boolean attribute:

```
node.setAttribute(attributeName, '');
// example:
document.body.setAttribute('hidden', '');
```

> Note the **empty string as the second argument**!

Use `node.removeAttribute(attributeName)` to remove an attribute as mentioned by others.

Comment: This is the only answer that actually directly responds to the question of how to set a non-reflected boolean attribute.

Comment: Correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

### To set an attribute

Use `element.setAttribute`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.setAttribute

If you add an `id` like this:

```
<p id="p1">
```

you can select the element like this:

```
var p1 = document.getElementById("p1");
```

### To set a Boolean attribute

According to the [W3C HTML4 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.3.4.2):

> *Boolean attributes may legally take a single value: the name of the attribute itself*

<s>so you can add your attribute like this:</s>

```
p1.setAttribute("contenteditable", "contenteditable");
```

### To set contentEditable

According to the [W3C HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#attr-contenteditable), the attribute `contentEditable` can have values `true`, `false` and `inherit`. Then you would have to do something like this:

```
p1.setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");
```

To be honest, I am also not sure which one is best in your situation.

Comment: That makes it `<p id="p1" contenteditable="true">` which is not the same as `<p id="p1" contenteditable>`

Comment: @ryanve It is the same. `contenteditable` is not a boolean attribute. See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9201499/96656 @TheNail You may want to revert that edit, as this has nothing to do with boolean attributes.

Comment: Is there a merge function for answers? :D

Answer (score 2):

```
element.setAttribute('contenteditable','contenteditable')
```

or to clear:

```
element.removeAttribute('contenteditable')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `element.dataset.example` to modify the value of the `data-example` attribute.

Comment: I think to be equivalent you'd set it to an empty string. `element.dataset.example = ""` See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9200712/proper-implementation-of-html5-dataset

Answer (score -2):

Quoted from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute):

> Boolean attributes are considered to be true if they're present on the
> element at all, regardless of their actual value; as a rule, you
> should specify the empty string ("") in value (some people use the
> attribute's name; this works but is non-standard).

**source:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute