# In jQuery, what kind of things are itemscopes, attributes or properties?

Tags: jquery, properties, attributes, microdata

If I want to dynamically set an element as a new itemscope and give it an itemtype, what would `itemscope` be from a jQuery point of view? In other words, should I use `.attr("itemscope", "")` or `.prop("itemscope", true)`?

As an example, let's say I want to add an `itemscope` to my `body` tag and give it the type `WebPage`:

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
```

I can use `$("body").attr("itemtype", "http://schema.org/WebPage")` for the type, but what about the `itemscope`?

The thing is, when I use `.prop('itemscope', true)` I don't see these changes reflected in HTML (i.e. there's no visible change in the DOM), whereas using `.attr('itemscope', '')` shows the changes but as an attribute. In other words, as `itemscope=''` rather than `itemscope`.

What is the valid way to add an `itemscope` to an element with JS/jQuery?

```js
var d = $("div");

d.attr('itemtype', 'http://schema.org/WebPage');
d.attr('itemscope', '');
d.prop('itemscope', true);
console.log(d.attr('itemtype'));
console.log(d.attr('itemscope'));
console.log(d.prop('itemscope'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div/>
```

Comment: You can try prop("itemscope", true)

Comment: `attr('itemscope', '')` shows `itemscope` (without `=''`) for me in Chromium’s DOM tree view.

Comment: @unor After some more testing, it seems that Firefox always renders `itemscope` with an empty string value, so I am assuming that `.attr` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`itemscope` attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/microdata.html#attr-itemscope) is a **boolean attribute**.

That means it can be specified in multiple ways (in the HTML syntax):

- `itemscope`
- `itemscope=""`
- `itemscope=''`
- `itemscope=itemscope`
- `itemscope="itemscope"`
- `itemscope='itemscope'`

(and variants with upper/mixed case and additional spaces at certain positions are possible, too)

(References from HTML 5.1: [2.4.2. Boolean attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/infrastructure.html#sec-boolean-attributes), [8.1.2.3. Attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/syntax.html#elements-attributes))

For adding it with JavaScript, see for example the question [*How to add boolean attribute using JavaScript*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9201471/1591669).